# Moving text across screen smoothly

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, textfield, bitmapdata

For a long time I've been searching for a solution to this problem, so I decided to post a tread instead when the search didn't clarify anything.

I have a textfield that is supposed to move across the screen. I've solved this by adding a speed to its x-value dynamically through an "enter-frame function". However, the movement is very "laggy" and consists of sudden "jumps" in the movement. I've tried a couple of possible solutions to this, all of them without luck.

- embedding fonts
- changing the textfield's antiAliasType
- using BitmapData like this:

  ```
  bmd = new BitmapData (myTextField.width, myTextField.height, true, 0);
  bmd.draw (myTextField);

  bm = new Bitmap (bmd);
  bm.x = myTextField.x;
  bm.y = myTextField.y;
  bm.cacheAsBitmap = true;
  bm.smoothing = true;
  this.addChild(bm);`
  ```

  And then moving the "bm" instance

None of these methods worked.

*EDIT: By request, I am adding the relevant code for the actual movement of the text.*

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, time);

private function time(evt:Event):void
{
    bm.x-= textSpeed;
}
```

The variable `textSpeed` is defined as a `public static var`. Its value is 2.

*EDIT2: I've prepared a clean fla-file with nothing but moving text. The same lag occurs for me also here. The code is in the actions panel. [Download link](http://speedy.sh/Brxh5/TextMovementTesting.fla)

Comment: Show us how you are moving it. (and you don't need to "cacheAsBitmap" a Bitmap... ;) )

Comment: when converting to bitmap, are you removing the original text field?  What's your framerate?  What other things are you animating at the same time?

Comment: @Fygo: I've added the code for movement. I've also removed the "cacheAsBitmap" line, however, that didn't make any difference.

Comment: @LDMediaServices: No, I'm not removing it at any time. It is defined as invisible from the beginning, and not moving. My framerate is 30,00. Yes, it does occur other animations in the program, but not at any time. I've noticed that the "severity" of the lagging descriped in my post doesn't change significantly depending on the amount of other animations in the program.

Comment: I have honestly no idea why this occurs. Can you prepare a "clean" fla as an example and upload it somewhere? (no other code, only for drawing and moving)

Comment: @Fygo: Done. See the bottom of the question.

Answer (score 1):

the way Flash IDE works, is that setting the framerate is actually the 'maximum' framerate. That is, it doesn't force the animation to run at that rate - it can vary depending on the machine and available resources.

As far as I know, there's no way to force Flash to run at a certain framerate - the best way to make animations 'smooth' is to use Tween classes like TweenLite.

If you NEED to animate by incrementing position values, then I suggest making it time based instead, for example:

```
var fps = 24;

var moveTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000/fps);


moveTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onMoveTimer);
moveTimer.start();
function onMoveTimer(e:TimerEvent){
    bm.x -= 1;
}
```

Again, this doesn't solve the smoothness of the animation, but it will be much more reliable across different machines than using enter frame.

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the framerate. Because you naturally try to read text as it animates, you can generally notice the gaps between frames at 24fps. Try setting `stage.frameRate` to 30, 48, or 60 (60 being the max) and see if that solves your issues. I've had similar issues with animating text in the past and increasing frame rate has fixed them.

I would also recommend only increasing it as needed. You are much more likely to drop frames with a higher frame rate (makes logical sense; each frame has less time to calculate as frame rate increases), so you might want to do something like:

```
stage.frameRate = 48;
// run animations here
stage.frameRate = 24; // in an Event.COMPLETE handler
```

That will make sure your animations are smooth while giving the rest of your application the best shot of running well on lesser devices. If you are running a lot of animations, you might consider keeping it elevated permanently.

You should also look into using the Greensock animation library (TweenLite/TweenMax) instead of Flash's built-in tweening. Greensock has a vastly superior API, both in terms of features and performances, especially on mobile.

Comment: I've tried increasing the framerate, however that only seems to make the lagging more visible. I'd like to test this animation library you mention, though.